# Mockito initMocks with @BeforeClass

Tags: mockito

Is there any reason why everybody uses @Before instead of @BeforeClass with initMocks? In my case I have only one method call in setup method and that is MockitoAnnotations.initMocks. @BeforeClass is even faster.

Comment: initMocks is used to initialize the Mocks you have created in your class with `@Mock`. If you do init even before class is loaded, how can the mocks defined in the class can be initialized

Comment: What instance do you pass in to `initMocks`? When `@BeforeClass` is run, [your test case does not have an instance created yet](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/122#issuecomment-835012).

Answer (score 4):

@BeforeClass, as the name suggest is run after class is loaded and no object exist. So all variable which you initialize need to be static. So, if you want to reuse this static variable in all testcases, as base setup input data, then you can do ahead with using @BeforeClass.

@Before is useful, then you want to reset the data before each test case gets called, so you are sure, anyone changing the input base data, does not impact the with what the next test is called.

coming to initmock, you can do via @Mock, @InjectMocks and using @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SampleTest {

@InjectMocks
private ClassA classA;

@Mock
private ClassB classB

// @BeforeClass and other test methods 
}
```

In above code,

```
1. Instance of ClassA will be created
2. Mock object of ClassB will be created
3. classB will be injected in ClassA object created in step 1
```